# Why don't SQLAlchemy show up in the search results of `pip3 search SQLAlchemy`?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pip

I wanted to install SQLAlchemy for Python 3 for working with databases.

I searched for the package using `pip3 search SQLAlchemy`, but I didn't find [SQLAlchemy](https://pypi.org/project/SQLAlchemy/) as part of the results.

Why don't SQLAlchemy show up in the output below, when the package is available on PyPI?

https://pypi.org/project/SQLAlchemy/

**SQLAlchemy 1.3.15**

```
pip install SQLAlchemy
```

**`pip3 --version`:**

```
$ pip3 --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

**`pip3 search SQLAlchemy`**:

```
$ pip3 search SQLAlchemy
sqlalchemy-nuodb (2.3.1)             - SQLAlchemy for NuoDB
sqlalchemy-filterparams (0.9.0)      - SQLAlchemy Filterparams
sqlalchemy-manager (0.0.2)           - Manager for SQLAlchemy
SQLAlchemy-Ext (0.2)                 - Extensions of SQLAlchemy
sqlalchemy-ceodbc (0.1.0)            - SQLAlchemy dialect for ceODBC
SQLAlchemy-JSONAPI (4.0.10)          - JSONAPI Mixin for SQLAlchemy
bonobo-sqlalchemy (0.6.1)            - Bonobo SQLAlchemy Extension
polymorphic-sqlalchemy (0.2.6)       - Polymorphic relations for SQLAlchemy
sqlalchemy-zdb (0.1.3)               - SQLAlchemy support for ZomboDB
sqlalchemy-access (1.0.3)            - MS Access for SQLAlchemy
serafin-sqlalchemy (0.1)             - SQLAlchemy integration for serafin
vertica-sqlalchemy (0.13)            - Vertica dialect for sqlalchemy
sqlalchemy-commons (0.0.2)           - SQLAlchemy common models
sqlalchemy-facets (0.1.3)            - Faceted search for SQLAlchemy
bottle-sqlalchemy (0.4.3)            - SQLAlchemy integration for Bottle.
spotlight-sqlalchemy (1.0.2)         - SQLAlchemy plugin for Spotlight.
sqlalchemy-phoenix (0.4.0)           - SQLAlchemy dialect for Phoenix
WSME-SQLAlchemy (0.4)                - SQLAlchemy support for WSME
sqlalchemy-informix (0.2.4)          - SQLAlchemy informix backend
impaf-sqlalchemy (0.1)               - SQLAlchemy plugin for Impaf.
snowflake-sqlalchemy (1.2.3)         - Snowflake SQLAlchemy Dialect
SQLAlchemy-Paginator (0.1)           - Paginator for SQLAlchemy ORM
fresco-sqlalchemy (0.1)              - Fresco/SQLAlchemy integration
async-sqlalchemy (1.0.0)             - asyncio sqlalchemy support
sqlalchemy-teradata (0.9.0.dev0)     - Teradata dialect for SQLAlchemy
sqlalchemy-django (0.0.4)            - similar flask sqlalchemy
sqlalchemy-vertica (0.0.5)           - Vertica dialect for sqlalchemy
sqlalchemy-gbase8s (0.0.6)           - SQLAlchemy gbase8s backend
tornado-sqlalchemy (0.7.0)           - SQLAlchemy support for Tornado
sqlalchemy-turbodbc (0.1.0)          - SQLAlchemy dialect for Turbodbc
morepath-sqlalchemy (0.1)            - Morepath SQLAlchemy Demo
sqlalchemy-clickhouse (0.1.5.post0)  - ClickHouse SQLAlchemy Dialect
sqlalchemy-bundle (1.03)             - SqlAlchemy support for applauncher
sqlalchemy-aio (0.15.0)              - Async support for SQLAlchemy.
mobilitydb-sqlalchemy (0.2.1)        - MobilityDB extensions to SQLAlchemy
sqlalchemy-media (0.17.4)            - Sqlalchemy asset manager
WTForms-SQLAlchemy (0.1)             - SQLAlchemy tools for WTForms
sqlalchemy-exasol (2.0.9)            - EXASOL dialect for SQLAlchemy
pyApp-SQLAlchemy (1.0.1)             - SQLAlchemy Extension for PyApp
graphene-sqlalchemy (2.2.2)          - Graphene SQLAlchemy integration
SQLAlchemy-Dao (1.3.1)               - Simple wrapper for sqlalchemy.
CherryPy-SQLAlchemy (0.5.3)          - Use SQLAlchemy with CherryPy
sqlalchemy-gbase8t (0.0.2)           - SQLAlchemy gbase8t backend
takumi-sqlalchemy (0.1.5)            - Sqlalchemy utilities for Takumi
clickhouse-sqlalchemy (0.1.2)        - Simple ClickHouse SQLAlchemy Dialect
apistar-sqlalchemy (0.3.2)           - SQLAlchemy integration for API Star.
redshift-sqlalchemy (0.4.1)          - Amazon Redshift Dialect for sqlalchemy
sqlalchemy-batteries (0.4.5)         - Various batteries for SQLAlchemy models
sqlalchemy-qubole (1.0.6)            - Qubole Presto/Hive for SQLAlchemy
SQLAlchemy-Unchained (0.10.0)        - Improved declarative SQLAlchemy models
SQLAlchemy-Continuum (1.3.9)         - Versioning and auditing extension for SQLAlchemy.
sqlalchemy-hana (0.4.0)              - SQLAlchemy dialect for SAP HANA
sqlalchemy-debug (0.3.2)             - a tool for debug sqlalchemy model
sqlalchemy-pervasive (0.1.3)         - SQLAlchemy Dialect for Pervasive PSQL
sqlalchemy-sphinx (0.9.0)            - SQLAlchemy extension for dealing with SphinxQL
sqlalchemy-redshift (0.7.7)          - Amazon Redshift Dialect for sqlalchemy
sqlalchemy-migrate (0.13.0)          - Database schema migration for SQLAlchemy
sqlalchemy-lightening (0.5.0)        - making SQLAlchemy great again
sqlalchemy-model (0.0.1)             - sqlalchemy data to dict model
SQLAlchemy-Fixtures (0.1.6)          - Functional fixtures for SQLAlchemy models.
sqlalchemy-datatables (2.0.1)        - SQLAlchemy integration of jQuery DataTables
restible-sqlalchemy (0.2)            - SQLAlchemy integration for restible library
sqlalchemy-stubs (0.3)               - SQLAlchemy stubs and mypy plugin
nameko-sqlalchemy (1.5.0)            - SQLAlchemy dependency for nameko services
temporal-sqlalchemy (0.5.0)          - Temporal Extensions for SQLAlchemy ORM
SQLAlchemy-Sluggable (0.1.1)         - Configurable slugs to SQLAlchemy models.
sqlalchemy-dst (1.0.1)               - SQLAlchemy Dictionary Serialization Tools.
Painless-SQLAlchemy (1.0.2)          - Simplified filtering and serialization for SQLAlchemy
SQLAlchemy-i18n (1.0.3)              - Internationalization extension for SQLAlchemy models.
SQLAlchemy-Utils (0.36.3)            - Various utility functions for SQLAlchemy.
sqlalchemy-filters (0.10.0)          - A library to filter SQLAlchemy queries.
sqlalchemy-nav (0.0.4)               - SQLAlchemy-Nav provides SQLAlchemy Mixins for creating navigation bars compatible with Bootstrap
ripozo-sqlalchemy (1.0.2)            - Integrates SQLAlchemy with ripozo to easily create sqlalchemy backed Hypermedia/HATEOAS/REST apis
sqlalchemy-fsm (2.0.8)               - Finite state machine field for sqlalchemy
sqlalchemy-greenplum (0.0.1)         - SQLAlchemy dialect for Pivotal Greenplum Database
sqlalchemy-pysqlite3 (0.0.4)         - SQLAlchemy dialect to use pysqlite3 dbapi2
dbreak-sqlalchemy (0.0.1)            - Plugin for dbreak to handle SQLAlchemy connections
asphalt-sqlalchemy (3.1.4)           - SQLAlchemy integration component for the Asphalt framework
fdt-sqlalchemy (0.0.4)               - Flask-debugtoolbar configurable SQLAlchemy panel
hypr-sqlalchemy (0.2.1)              - An extension to add supprt for SQLAlchemy to Hypr.
OpenAPI-SQLAlchemy (0.7.0)           - Maps an OpenAPI schema to SQLAlchemy models.
sqlalchemy-modelid (0.0.2)           - Base with a `model_id` property for SQLAlchemy models
hypothesis-sqlalchemy (0.3.2)        - ``hypothesis`` strategies for generating ``SQLAlchemy`` objects.
sqlalchemy-views (0.2.4)             - Adds CreateView and DropView constructs to SQLAlchemy
pytest-sqlalchemy (0.2.1)            - pytest plugin with sqlalchemy related fixtures
verktyg-sqlalchemy (0.3.0)           - Library for using sqlalchemy in vertyg applications
sqlalchemy-elasticquery (0.0.3)      - Use ElasticSearch query search in SQLAlchemy.
SQLAlchemy-Rope (0.1.0)              - Wrapper for SQLAlchemy to Thread-local use
sqlalchemy-profile (0.1.0)           - SQLAlchemy statement profiler for unit testing
sqlalchemy-hilo (0.1.2)              - HiLo primary key generators for sqlalchemy
sqlalchemy-mongobi (0.2.1)           - MongoDB connector for BI SQLAlchemy Dialect
sqlalchemy-pagination (0.0.2)        - A small utility to paginate SqlAlchemy queries.
FastAPI-SQLAlchemy (0.1.3)           - Adds simple SQLAlchemy support to FastAPI
Broadway-SQLAlchemy (0.0.1)          - A broadway extension wrapping Flask-SQLAlchemy
sqlalchemy-plus (0.2.0)              - Create Views and Materialized Views with SqlAlchemy
sqlalchemy-citext (1.6-1)            - A sqlalchemy plugin that allows postgres use of CITEXT.
attrs-sqlalchemy (0.1.0)             - Add dunder-methods to SQLAlchemy models with attrs
marshmallow-sqlalchemy (0.22.3)      - SQLAlchemy integration with the marshmallow (de)serialization library
SQLAlchemy-JSONField (0.9.0)         - SQLALchemy JSONField implementation for storing dicts at SQL
sqlalchemy-dict (0.7.0)              - sqlalchemy extension for interacting models with python dictionary.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ pip search sqlalchemy | wc -l
100
```

It seems there is a (reasonable) limit on how many results `pip search` returns and pure `SQLAlchemy` doesn't fit.

There is no way for `pip search` to increase the limit (it's imposed at the server-side) and no way to ask for a different page.

Comment: Thank you, is there any way to restrict the search so that `SQLAlchemy` would get returned?

Comment: I don't know of any one. `pip search` is actually quite a strange search. For example, you cannot search for a substring. Try `pip search sqlalch`